# Split a large pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe with 423244 lines. I want to split this in to 4. I tried the following code which gave an error? `ValueError: array split does not result in an equal division`

```
for item in np.split(df, 4):
    print item
```

How to split this dataframe in to 4 groups?

Comment: We want a `np.split(df, N)` function please.

Answer (score 345, accepted):

Use [`np.array_split`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html):

```
Docstring:
Split an array into multiple sub-arrays.

Please refer to the ``split`` documentation.  The only difference
between these functions is that ``array_split`` allows
`indices_or_sections` to be an integer that does *not* equally
divide the axis.
```

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'bar',
   ...:                           'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
   ...:                    'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three',
   ...:                           'two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],
   ...:                    'C' : randn(8), 'D' : randn(8)})

In [3]: print df
     A      B         C         D
0  foo    one -0.174067 -0.608579
1  bar    one -0.860386 -1.210518
2  foo    two  0.614102  1.689837
3  bar  three -0.284792 -1.071160
4  foo    two  0.843610  0.803712
5  bar    two -1.514722  0.870861
6  foo    one  0.131529 -0.968151
7  foo  three -1.002946 -0.257468

In [4]: import numpy as np
In [5]: np.array_split(df, 3)
Out[5]: 
[     A    B         C         D
0  foo  one -0.174067 -0.608579
1  bar  one -0.860386 -1.210518
2  foo  two  0.614102  1.689837,
      A      B         C         D
3  bar  three -0.284792 -1.071160
4  foo    two  0.843610  0.803712
5  bar    two -1.514722  0.870861,
      A      B         C         D
6  foo    one  0.131529 -0.968151
7  foo  three -1.002946 -0.257468]
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much! In addition to this I want to apply some function to each group?How to access groups one by one?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage -- `array_split` returns a list of DataFrames, so you can just loop through the list...

Comment: I'm splitting the dataframe since it is too large. I want to take the first group and apply the function, then the second group and apply function etc. so how do I access each group?

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage -- I am not sure what do you mean. You can access each df the same way you would any list element... If you continue having problems, please ask a new question and specify the function that you are trying to use on the dfs...

Comment: Thanks root,I have accepted your answer :)!..This is what I wanted...group = np.array_split(df, 3), group[0].apply(func)etc.

Comment: How do you not get an AttributeError as Dataframe has no 'size'.

Comment: This answer is outdated: `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'size'`

Comment: Answer works great! Very tight and concise (e.g. Pythonic) for looping over chunks of data frames when doing heavy computations

Comment: why does this work? i realize `np.split` works on arrays and dataframe is an np array under the hood but how come the function returns a list of dataframes instead of arrays.. seems a bit magical?

Comment: Any ideas on the limit of rows to use the Numpy array_split method? I have a dataframe with +6m rows and would like to split it in 20 or so chunks but his method just appears to be taking forever. Thanks

Comment: @root , can i split df by ratio? for example, 6:1

Comment: want to split a big dataframe in to a smaller dataframes of 50 records each , how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 84):

I wanted to do the same, and I had first problems with the split function, then problems with installing pandas 0.15.2, so I went back to my old version, and wrote a little function that works very well. I hope this can help!

```
# input - df: a Dataframe, chunkSize: the chunk size
# output - a list of DataFrame
# purpose - splits the DataFrame into smaller chunks
def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size = 10000): 
    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])
    return chunks
```

Comment: much faster than using np.array_split()

Comment: The correct way to calculate numberChunks

import math

numberChunks = math.ceil(len(df) / chunkSize)

Comment: @SergeyLeyko is correct. Otherwise you get an empty dataframe at the end of the `chunks` list when `df` size is equally divicible by chunk size. Here's an alternative for num_chunks

`num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size + (1 if len(df) % chunk_size else 0)`

Comment: If `df.index` is not consecutive, `.iloc` has to be used, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49415851/1116842).

Answer (score 49):

Be aware that `np.array_split(df, 3)` splits the dataframe into 3 sub-dataframes, while the `split_dataframe` function defined in [@elixir's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28882020/2486302), when called as `split_dataframe(df, chunk_size=3)`, splits the dataframe every `chunk_size` rows.

**Example:**

With `np.array_split`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11], columns=['TEST'])
df_split = np.array_split(df, 3)
```

...you get 3 sub-dataframes:

```
df_split[0] # 1, 2, 3, 4
df_split[1] # 5, 6, 7, 8
df_split[2] # 9, 10, 11
```

With `split_dataframe`:

```
df_split2 = split_dataframe(df, chunk_size=3)
```

...you get 4 sub-dataframes:

```
df_split2[0] # 1, 2, 3
df_split2[1] # 4, 5, 6
df_split2[2] # 7, 8, 9
df_split2[3] # 10, 11
```

Hope I'm right, and that this is useful.

Comment: is there an easy way to make this process random. I can only think of adding a rondom column, splitting and removing the random column but there might be an easier way

Comment: do they have to be equal chunk sizes?

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. Take my upvote!

Comment: Thanks @Gilbertor! To which library does the module "split_dataframe" belong? I can't import it neither find a library which it belongs to...

Comment: @soph It's defined in the answer by elixir here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28882020/5060208

Answer (score 34):

I guess now we can use plain `iloc` with `range` for this.

```
chunk_size = int(df.shape[0] / 4)
for start in range(0, df.shape[0], chunk_size):
    df_subset = df.iloc[start:start + chunk_size]
    process_data(df_subset)
    ....
```

Comment: Also consider [this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65800824/) which does the same using the `more_itertools` package.

Answer (score 11):

you can use list comprehensions to do this in a single line

```
n = 4
chunks = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

Comment: But also see the important note about COPY vs VIEW in my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69409948/6939217

Answer (score 8):

Caution:

`np.array_split` doesn't work with numpy-1.9.0. I checked out: It works with 1.8.1.

**Error:**

> Dataframe has no 'size' attribute

Comment: i filed a bug in the pandas github: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/8846

seems it is already fixed for pandas 0.15.2

Answer (score 7):

building on @elixir's answer...
I'd suggest using a generator
to avoid loading all the chunks in memory:

```py
def chunkit(df, chunk_size = 10000): 
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size
    if len(df) % chunk_size != 0:
        num_chunks += 1
    for i in range(num_chunks):
        yield df[i*chunk_size:(i + 1) * chunk_size]
```

Answer (score 7):

I like a one-liners, so @LucyDrops answer works for me.

However, there is one **important thing**: add a `.copy()` if chunks should be COPY of original `df` parts:

```py
chunks = [df[i:i+n].copy() for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

**Otherwise** there is a high chance to receive the next warning during the further processing of `chunks` (in loop for example):

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
```

(see the details in the [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy))

Comment: From the link you posted "it’s very hard to predict whether it will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees)"

Comment: @JoeyBaruch, the answer has been updated. Thanks

Comment: In Pandas, when warned about trying to use a copy, I've found the problem was always because a copy was NOT being used and solution is always to add a `.copy()`. If that dev would just change it to `on a non-copy`, whatever the deal is, just make it less unclear, would be appreciated, and add the currently missing line number

Answer (score 5):

You can use `groupby`, assuming you have an integer enumerated index:

```
import math
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(sample=np.arange(99)))
rows_per_subframe = math.ceil(len(df) / 4.)

subframes = [i[1] for i in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//rows_per_subframe)]
```

Note: `groupby` returns a tuple in which the 2nd element is the dataframe, thus the slightly complicated extraction.

```
>>> len(subframes), [len(i) for i in subframes]
(4, [25, 25, 25, 24])
```

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced `np.array_split` not working with Pandas DataFrame. My solution was to only split the index of the DataFrame and then introduce a new column with the "group" label:

```
indexes = np.array_split(df.index,N, axis=0)
for i,index in enumerate(indexes):
   df.loc[index,'group'] = i
```

This makes groupby operations very convenient, such as for calculating the mean value of each group:

```
df.groupby(by='group').mean()
```

Comment: Anyone using `.loc` over `.iloc` should definitely remain aware of the difference between the two.