# Python Pandas to_pickle cannot pickle large dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I have a dataframe "DF" with with 500,000 rows. Here are the data types per column:

```
ID      int64
time    datetime64[ns]
data    object
```

each entry in the "data" column is an array with size = [5,500]

When I try to save this dataframe using

```
DF.to_pickle("my_filename.pkl")
```

it returned me the following error:

```
     12     """
     13     with open(path, 'wb') as f:
---> 14         pkl.dump(obj, f, protocol=pkl.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL) 

OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I also try this method but I get the same error:

```
import pickle


with open('my_filename.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(DF, f)
```

I try to save 10 rows of this dataframe:

```
DF.head(10).to_pickle('test_save.pkl')
```

and I have no error at all. Therefore, it can save small DF but not large DF.

I am using python 3, ipython notebook 3 in Mac.

Please help me to solve this problem. I really need to save this DF to a pickle file. I can not find the solution in the internet.

Comment: Have you tried cPickle? Using pickle for lots of data is suboptimal anyway. Not that I'm convinved it fixes the problem, but it is possible.

Comment: cPickle is not available in python 3.

Comment: How large exactly is the dataframe in memory?

Comment: This is a bug, to be fixed yet: http://bugs.python.org/issue24658

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably not the answer you were hoping for but this is what I did......

Split the dataframe into smaller chunks using np.array_split (although numpy functions are not guaranteed to work, it does now, although there used to be a bug for it).

Then pickle the smaller dataframes.

When you unpickle them use pandas.append or pandas.concat to glue everything back together.

I agree it is a fudge and suboptimal. If anyone can suggest a "proper" answer I'd be interested in seeing it, but I think it as simple as dataframes are not supposed to get above a certain size.

[Split a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 16):

Until there is a fix somewhere on pickle/pandas side of things, 
I'd say a better option is to use alternative IO backend. HDF is suitable for large datasets (GBs). So you don't need to add additional split/combine logic.

```
df.to_hdf('my_filename.hdf','mydata',mode='w')

df = pd.read_hdf('my_filename.hdf','mydata')
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use compression. It worked for me.

`data_df.to_pickle('data_df.pickle.gzde', compression='gzip')`

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and traced the cause to a memory issue. According to [this recourse](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995236/how-can-i-prevent-my-system-from-crashing-or-becoming-unusable-due-to-high-ram-u) it's usually not actually caused by the memory itself, but the movement of too many resources into the swap space. I was able to save the large pandas file by disableing swap all together withe the command (provided in that link):

```
    swapoff -a
```