# Writing large Pandas Dataframes to CSV file in chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, export-to-csv, large-data

How do I write out a large data files to a CSV file in chunks?

I have a set of large data files (1M rows x 20 cols). However, only 5 or so columns of the data files are of interest to me.

I want to make things easier by making copies of these files with only the columns of interest so I have smaller files to work with for post-processing. So I plan to read the file into a dataframe, then write to csv file.

I've been looking into reading large data files in chunks into a dataframe. However, I haven't been able to find anything on how to write out the data to a csv file in chunks.

Here is what I'm trying now, but this doesn't append the csv file:

```py
with open(os.path.join(folder, filename), 'r') as src:
    chunks = pd.read_csv(src, sep='\t',skiprows=(0,1,2),header=(0), chunksize=1000)
    for chunk in chunks:
        chunk.to_csv(
            os.path.join(folder, new_folder, "new_file_" + filename), 
            columns = [['TIME','STUFF']]
        )
```

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Solution:

```
header = True
for chunk in chunks:

    chunk.to_csv(os.path.join(folder, new_folder, "new_file_" + filename),
        header=header, cols=[['TIME','STUFF']], mode='a')

    header = False
```

Notes:

- The `mode='a'` tells pandas to append.
- We only write a column header on the first chunk.

Comment: I've noticed that when I append using mode='a', the column labels are written after every chunk. How do I make sure column labels only appear at the beginning of the file?

Comment: You can pass header=None to all but the first chunk

Comment: You could do `for i, chunk in chunks:`, and then `header=(i==0)`

Comment: I wound up using this solution with this other solution to split a dataframe into chunks first: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 23):

Check out the `chunksize` argument in the `to_csv` method. [Here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) are the docs.

Writing to file would look like:

```
df.to_csv("path/to/save/file.csv", chunksize=1000, cols=['TIME','STUFF'])
```

Comment: Hmm I got the following error using your proposed method:    AttributeError: 'TextFileReader' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Your answer is still assuming I'm reading into "df" in chunks?

Comment: This is for a complete DataFrame.

Comment: this is not helpful when streaming a giant dataframe from one file to another, in that case mode='a' is better.

Comment: @denfromufa Is that for sure? chunksize could mean writing in batches, could it not? And then it would have to be done in `append` mode anyway. Or am I missing something? I do not know the technical details, though, just a guess. Has anybody more insight into this, is this here the same as the accepted answer with its loop?

Comment: I can assure that this worked on a 50 MB file on 700000 rows with chunksize 5000 many times faster than a normal csv writer that loops over batches. I have not checked the loop over dataframes in `append` mode as in the accepted answer, but this answer cannot be bad at least. Brought down the Cloud Function time down to 62s from >9min timeout limit before (I do not even know how long it would have taken for writing all data, but much longer, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you only read the columns of interest and then save it?

```
file_in = os.path.join(folder, filename)
file_out = os.path.join(folder, new_folder, 'new_file' + filename)

df = pd.read_csv(file_in, sep='\t', skiprows=(0, 1, 2), header=0, names=['TIME', 'STUFF'])
df.to_csv(file_out)
```

Comment: Just in case I came across files that were so big that I would have to read in as chunks. I don't believe your code would allow me to do that, correct?

Comment: Correct, but it is still much more efficient.  If that were the case, you would still need to chunk or else use the csv module.