# Is it possible to write json chunk by chunk with pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a web server (tornado), and want to serialize a large dataframe to json but chunk by chunk, not creating the whole json string then sending it.

Is that possible ?

Comment: See if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531195/writing-panda-dataframes-to-csv-file-in-chunks

Comment: Yes !! It lead me to my answer ! thx Hassan !

Answer (score 0):

The http server (tornado) implements so this works :

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
impot pandas as pd

df=pf.DataFrame({"test":[1,2,3,4]})

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        df.to_json(self)
```