# How to export a dataframe to csv in chunks of 500 rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large dataframe which i export to a CSV and upload to a third party product. The third party product can only accept uploads of max 500 rows of my data so I am wondering how to export a dataframe into smaller files.

at the moment my code reads:

```
df.to_csv("Export.csv",index=False)
```

But ideally would like code to export files so that it gives:

```
Export1.csv
Export2.csv
Export3.csv
```

etc until it is all completed and each with 500 rows (and then whatever is left over). Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Writing large Pandas Dataframes to CSV file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531195/writing-large-pandas-dataframes-to-csv-file-in-chunks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- you can use `df.groupby` function to split df in a chunk of 500. And save each chunk. You can see the reference here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/25703030/6996326)

```
import numpy as np
no_of_rows = 500
for k,g in df.groupby(np.arange(len(df))//no_of_rows):
    g.to_csv('Export{}.csv'.format(k+1), index=False)
```