# Python to modify a csv file, duplicate and format a column, and save output

Tags: python, pandas, performance, csv, formatting

I am trying to figure out a way with the pandas library to take a 3 column csv file and turn it into a 5 column csv file with formatting in place for the last column. I Then need to save the output. I was able to write this in powershell but I cant figure it out in python and I need it to be extraordinary efficient. I am using a 3 column 140 million row file with this. Example of what im trying to do:

Test-data 1234567 123456789

Test-data 1234567 123456789

To ->

Test-data 1234567 123456789 123-45-6789 123/45/6789

Test-data 1234567 1234667890 123-45-6789 123/45/6789

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Are u going to assign same values to the two new columns across rows??

Comment: No they will be based on the values in column 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example solution

```
import pandas as pd

chunksize = 10 ** 6
for chunk in pd.read_csv("sample_data.csv", chunksize=chunksize, engine="c", header=None, sep=" ", dtype="string"):
    chunk[3] = chunk[2].map(lambda x: x[:3] + "-" + x[3:5] + "-" + x[5:])
    chunk[4] = chunk[2].map(lambda x: x[:3] + "/" + x[3:5] + "/" + x[5:])
    print(chunk.head(10))

    chunk.to_csv("sample_output.csv", header=None, mode='a')
```

Where I have used the following as points of reference:

[Writing large Pandas Dataframes to CSV file in chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38531195/writing-large-pandas-dataframes-to-csv-file-in-chunks)

[How do I read a large csv file with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962114/how-do-i-read-a-large-csv-file-with-pandas)