# Pandas - split large excel file

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have an excel file with about 500,000 rows and I want to split it to several excel file, each with 50,000 rows.

I want to do it with pandas so it will be the quickest and easiest.

any ideas how to make it?

thank you for your help

Comment: does you excel file have only one sheet with data?

Answer (score 10):

Assuming that your Excel file has only one (first) sheet containing data, I'd make use of `chunksize` parameter:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

i=0
for df in pd.read_excel(file_name, chunksize=50000):
    df.to_excel('/path/to/file_{:02d}.xlsx'.format(i), index=False)
    i += 1
```

**UPDATE:**

```
chunksize = 50000
df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
for chunk in np.split(df, len(df) // chunksize):
    chunk.to_excel('/path/to/file_{:02d}.xlsx'.format(i), index=False)
```

Comment: sorry for the delay but for some reason it raises an error which says `Reading an Excel file in chunks is not implemented` any ideas?

Comment: @TheDaJon, what is your pandas version: `pd.__version__`?

Comment: 0.17.1 this is my version

Comment: I was happy too fast... it does split the file, though the chunks are always bigger than what I choosed. any idea why?

Comment: array split does not result in an equal division, when there are odd  number of records

Answer (score 3):

use np.split_array as per this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17315875/1394890
if you get

array split does not result in an equal division

Answer (score 1):

As explained by MaxU, I will also make use of a variable chunksize and divide the total number of rows in large file into required number of rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

chunksize = 50000
i=0
df = pd.read_excel("path/to/file.xlsx")
for chunk in np.split(df, len(df) // chunksize):
    chunk.to_excel('path/to/destination/folder/file_{:02d}.xlsx'.format(i), index=True)
    i += 1
```

Hope this would help you.

Comment: you are joking man ...

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
l = pd.read_excel("inputfilename.xlsx")
total_size = 500,000
chunk_size = 50000
for i in range(0, total_size, chunk_size):
    df = l[i:i+chunk_size]
    df.to_excel(str(i)+"outputfilename.xlsx")
```

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a explanation

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a function for this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def split_excel(file_name, n):  # n: number of chunks or parts (number of outputed excel files)
    df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    l = len(df)
    c = l // n # c: number of rows
    r = l % c

    if r != 0:  # if it is not divisible
        df[-r:].to_excel(f'part_{l//c+1}.xlsx', index=False)
        df = df[:-r]

    i = 0
    for part in np.split(df, l//c):
        part.to_excel(f'part_{i}.xlsx', index=False)
        i += 1
        
        
split_excel('my_file.xlsx')
```