# Pandas dataframe to_csv - split into multiple output files

Tags: python, pandas

What is the best /easiest way to split a very large data frame (50GB) into multiple outputs (horizontally)?

I thought about doing something like:

```
stepsize = int(1e8)
for id, i in enumerate(range(0,df.size,stepsize)): 
    start = i 
    end = i + stepsize-1 #neglect last row ...
    df.ix[start:end].to_csv('/data/bs_'+str(id)+'.csv.out')
```

But I bet there is a smarter solution out there?

As noted by [jakevdp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2937831/jakevdp), [HDF5](https://docs.h5py.org/en/stable/) is a better way to  store huge amounts of numerical data, however it doesn't meet my business requirements.

Answer (score 25):

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe) brought me to a satisfying solution using:

- [`numpy.array_split(object, number_of_chunks)`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.split.html)

```py
for idx, chunk in enumerate(np.array_split(df, number_of_chunks)):
    chunk.to_csv(f'/data/bs_{idx}.csv')
```

Comment: You have attached the wrong link, it should be, https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html

Answer (score 17):

Use id in the filename else it will not work. You missed `id`, and without `id`, it gives an error.

```
for id, df_i in  enumerate(np.array_split(df, number_of_chunks)):
    df_i.to_csv('/data/bs_{id}.csv'.format(id=id))
```