# Pandas - Slice large dataframe into chunks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have a large dataframe (>3MM rows) that I'm trying to pass through a function (the one below is largely simplified), and I keep getting a `Memory Error` message.

I think I'm passing too large of a dataframe into the function, so I'm trying to:

1) Slice the dataframe into smaller chunks **(preferably sliced by `AcctName`)**

2) Pass the dataframe into the function

3) Concatenate the dataframes back into one large dataframe

```
def trans_times_2(df):
    df['Double_Transaction'] = df['Transaction'] * 2

large_df 
AcctName   Timestamp    Transaction
ABC        12/1         12.12
ABC        12/2         20.89
ABC        12/3         51.93    
DEF        12/2         13.12
DEF        12/8          9.93
DEF        12/9         92.09
GHI        12/1         14.33
GHI        12/6         21.99
GHI        12/12        98.81
```

I know that my function works properly, since it will work on a smaller dataframe (e.g. 40,000 rows). I tried the following, but I was unsuccessful with concatenating the small dataframes back into one large dataframe.

```
def split_df(df):
    new_df = []
    AcctNames = df.AcctName.unique()
    DataFrameDict = {elem: pd.DataFrame for elem in AcctNames}
    key_list = [k for k in DataFrameDict.keys()]
    new_df = []
    for key in DataFrameDict.keys():
        DataFrameDict[key] = df[:][df.AcctNames == key]
        trans_times_2(DataFrameDict[key])
    rejoined_df = pd.concat(new_df)
```

**How I envision the dataframes being split:**

```
df1
AcctName   Timestamp    Transaction  Double_Transaction
ABC        12/1         12.12        24.24
ABC        12/2         20.89        41.78
ABC        12/3         51.93        103.86

df2
AcctName   Timestamp    Transaction  Double_Transaction
DEF        12/2         13.12        26.24
DEF        12/8          9.93        19.86
DEF        12/9         92.09        184.18

df3
AcctName   Timestamp    Transaction  Double_Transaction
GHI        12/1         14.33        28.66
GHI        12/6         21.99        43.98
GHI        12/12        98.81        197.62
```

Answer (score 158, accepted):

You can use list comprehension to split your dataframe into smaller dataframes contained in a list.

```
n = 200000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

Or use numpy `array_split`,

```
list_df = np.array_split(df, math.ceil(len(df)/n))
```

You can access the chunks with:

```
list_df[0]
list_df[1]
etc...
```

Then you can assemble it back into a one dataframe using pd.concat.

By AcctName

```
list_df = []

for n,g in df.groupby('AcctName'):
    list_df.append(g)
```

Comment: Thanks Scott! Is there a way to split into smaller dataframes based on `AcctName` instead of chunk size?

Comment: @WaltReed Try that second part using groupby.

Comment: Okay great, that worked! I'm calling this inside a function, but when I try to view the new dataframe *after* running the function, I get the error `NameError: name 'new_df' is not defined`. What am I missing here?

Comment: If you created that list onside the function then it is a local variable.  You may need to put the keyword global in front of list_df = []

Comment: Can use `len(df)` instead of `df.shape[0]`.

Comment: Your numpy method is not equivalent to the list comprehension. I think you intended it to be `np.array_split(df, math.ceil(len(df) / N))`? If the intention was to show two different approaches to chunking a df, I think the numpy method warrants some initial explanation. Even using `math.ceil()` wouldn't guarantee the same behaviour as shown in the [second example](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) in the docs

Answer (score 24):

I'd suggest using a dependency [`more_itertools`](https://github.com/more-itertools/more-itertools). It handles all edge cases like uneven partition of the dataframe and returns an iterator that will make things a tiny bit more efficient.

(updated using code from @Acumenus)

```
from more_itertools import sliced
CHUNK_SIZE = 5

index_slices = sliced(range(len(df)), CHUNK_SIZE)

for index_slice in index_slices:
  chunk = df.iloc[index_slice] # your dataframe chunk ready for use
```

Comment: Can't you just do something a bit more direct: `for chunk in sliced(df, CHUNK_SIZE)`?

Comment: @santon: Yes, no difference. The generator can only be iterated once anyway, so it doesn't make much sense to store it as a variable.

Answer (score 5):

I love @ScottBoston answer, although, I still haven't memorized the incantation. Here's a more verbose function that does the same thing:

```
def chunkify(df: pd.DataFrame, chunk_size: int):
    start = 0
    length = df.shape[0]

    # If DF is smaller than the chunk, return the DF
    if length <= chunk_size:
        yield df[:]
        return

    # Yield individual chunks
    while start + chunk_size <= length:
        yield df[start:chunk_size + start]
        start = start + chunk_size

    # Yield the remainder chunk, if needed
    if start < length:
        yield df[start:]
```

To rebuild the data frame, accumulate each chunk in a list, then `pd.concat(chunks, axis=1)`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the solutions.

I tried two suggested methods:

method 1:

```
measure = time.time()
n = 10**6
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0, df.shape[0], n)]
list_df[0]
print(time.time()-measure) # 0.00800180435180664 seconds
```

This is faster.

Method 2:

```
import math

measure = time.time()
n = 10**6
list_df = np.array_split(df, math.ceil(len(df)/n))
list_df[0]
print(time.time()-measure) # 56.50256133079529 seconds
```

This is slower.

Comment: For performance questions, please support your claims with references or your own measurements e.g. using time module

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the post with the time module to support my claim. Thank you.

Comment: If the performance difference is that large it is worth thinking about it. But I suspect this result varies greatly with the size of the dataframe and the number `n`

Comment: Yes. The dataframe size decides the time taken. The above difference is for df with 27 million rows.