# Splitting dataframe column into equal windows in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, chunks

I have a dataframe like the following  and I intend to extract windows with `size = 30` and then write for loop for each block of data and call other functions.

```
index = pd.date_range(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-04-01', freq='D')
data = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(len(index)), index = index, columns=['random'])
```

I found the following function, but I wonder if there is more efficient way to do so.

```
def split(df, chunkSize = 30): 
    listOfDf = list()
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    for i in range(numberChunks):
        listOfDf.append(df[i*chunkSize:(i+1)*chunkSize])
    return listOfDf
```

Comment: Can you please fix the indentation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use list comprehension. See this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-in-chunks/44729807#44729807) about how access dfs and another way to break up a dataframe.

```
n = 200000  #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]
```

Comment: A bit of added information: if your windows do not evenly divide your dataset (i.e. len(df)%n > 0), the last window will be smaller.  If that causes an issue, the @jdehesa solution evenly distributes the extra datapoints on the last (len(df)%n) windows such that every window length is either n or n-1 (but of course requires the use of numpy).

Answer (score 5):

You can do it efficiently with NumPy's [`array_split`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.array_split.html) like:

```
import numpy as np

def split(df, chunkSize = 30):
    numberChunks = len(df) // chunkSize + 1
    return np.array_split(df, numberChunks, axis=0)
```

Even though it is a NumPy function, it will return the split data frames with the correct indices and columns.