# how to split dataframe, process and combine in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, geopy

**Question** : Is there a straightforward way to split pandas dataframe into multiple groups based on index, apply a pre-defined function to calculate a new feature and combine the groups back to original shape with extended feature?

I'm trying to enrich features in NYC GreenTaxi Data as shown below,

*Loading data and defining process function*

```
import pandas as pd
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
import os
import urllib.request

#Downloading the data, if not present
if not os.path.exists('./gc_data_sept15.csv'):
    urllib.request.urlretrieve('https://s3.amazonaws.com/nyc-tlc/trip+data/green_tripdata_2015-09.csv', './gc_data_sept15.csv')  

#load the data
greentaxi_data = pd.read_csv('./gc_data_sept15.csv')

#functionality to get the county based on co-ordinates, using geolocator api of geopy
def getCounty(coords,geolocator):
    location = geolocator.reverse(coords)
    if location.raw is not None and location.raw['address']['county'] is not None:
        return location.raw['address']['county'].split()[0]
    else :
        return 'Unknown'
```

*Checking functionality over a subset*

```
#define geolocator and derive a Pickup_borough
subset_ = greentaxi_data[:100]

geolocator = Nominatim(timeout=5000)
subset_['Pickup_borough'] = subset_.apply(\
                                        lambda row: getCounty((row['Pickup_latitude'],\
                                                               row['Pickup_longitude']),geolocator),axis=1)
```

*This works*

```
>>> subset_['Pickup_borough'].head(5)
0     Kings
1    Bergen
2    Queens
3    Queens
4     Kings
```

**But when I try to do it on the original dataframe inspite of repeated attempts with an higher timeout, I keep getting 'Service timedout' after a certain index.**

So here's my question, Is there a way where I could split the dataframe to a subset of say 1000 indexes, apply the function above and combine the result back to original dataframe shape.

Original Data Size :

```
>>> greentaxi_data.shape
(1494926, 21)
```

Comment: See this SO post.. https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729807/6361531

Comment: hmm, it might work.. trying that out right away. I wanted to check if there exists a more pythonic way of doing it.