# The Dataframe.sample method does not return the correct indexs

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create multiple subsets from one dataset.
this in my code :

```
def create_subdatasets(data, number_of_subdataset):
    subset_len = int(round(len(data))/number_of_subdataset)
    subsets = []
    while (len(data)>0):
        subset = data.sample(subset_len)
        subsets.append(subset)
        data = data.drop(data.index[subset.index])
    return subsets
```

but have this error :

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-95-587e16cc1433> in <module>
      2 data2 = data
      3 data2 = data2.reset_index()
----> 4 subsets = create_subdatasets(data2, number_of_subdataset)
      5 print(len(subsets))

<ipython-input-94-3f8ca422541f> in create_subdatasets(data, number_of_subdataset)
      6         print(subset.index)
      7         subsets.append(subset)
----> 8         data = data.drop(data.index[subset.index])
      9         #data = data.reset_index()
     10     return subsets

~/anaconda3/envs/tf-gpu/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in __getitem__(self, key)    4289     4290         key = com.values_from_object(key)
-> 4291         result = getitem(key)    4292         if not is_scalar(result):    4293             return promote(result)

IndexError: index 5068 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 4995
```

I understand that indexes of the subset dataframe are different from indexes of data objects, I think this problem is due to the sample method, I'm not sure if this is correct or not. Can someone please help me solve this error.

Comment: IndexError (out of bounds) means that the position that u are trying to access in the object data (see line 8) doesn't exist.

Comment: Can I offer you a different way of dividing your dataframe into a list of chunks? https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729807/6361531

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You problem is happening because you are trying to subset your data.index using index labels.

Change this line:

```
data = data.drop(data.index[subset.index])
```

to

```
data = data.drop(subset.index)
```

However, if your dataframe isn't split to and exactly equal you will face a 
"ValueError: Cannot take a larger sample than population when 'replace=False'"  error next.