# How to shuffle segments of data without changing the order in the segments?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shuffle

I would like to shuffle each 5 rows together without changing the order in that group.

Answer (score 1):

Pulling from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729807/7253453

You can achieve this by

```py
import random 

n = 5 #chunk row size
list_df = [df[i:i+n] for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n)]

random.shuffle(list_df)

df = pd.concat(list_df)
```