# Kernel is dead and restarting automatically while running a cell for a training a regression model

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, regression

Iam doing the Bulldozer price calculation problem, using RandomForestRegressor.After removing all the missing values and converting all data into numeric, I try to fit and train the data into a model. The data set is pretty large about 412698 rows × 57 columns and using a 3gb Ram device.

here is my code

```
%%time
# Instantiate model
model = RandomForestRegressor(n_jobs=-1,
                             random_state=42)

# Fit the model 
model.fit(df_tmp.drop("SalePrice", axis=1), df_tmp["SalePrice"])
```

The data set is available in Kaggle and I am also attaching its link..
https://www.kaggle.com/c/bluebook-for-bulldozers/data

Comment: my recommendations
1. try to convert the pandas df to numpy array.
2. If its not fit into memory try to reduce the input size.
3. RandomForest will generate a tree with lots and lots of branch so by default, it will occupy too much memory. so try to use proper features

Answer (score 0):

You can use Batch processing when you have more data than your ram can handle. Sklearn is inbuilt with this feature you have to use the `warm_start` parameter in RandomForestRegressor

warm_start, default=False
When set to True, reuse the solution of the previous call to fit and add more estimators to the ensemble, otherwise, just fit a whole new forest

You can try something like this

```
import numpy as np

model = RandomForestClassifier(warm_start = True, n_jobs=-1,random_state=42)

for df_split in np.array_split(df_temp, 500): # split into 500 dataframes 
   model.fit(df_split.drop("SalePrice", axis=1), df_split["SalePrice"])
```

if you have memory errors while loading pandas data frame itself check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-in-chunks)

you can always use [google colab](https://colab.research.google.com) for better ram and gpu. It is free and very easy to start with