# How to speed up pandas dataframe creation from huge file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a file bigger than 7GB. I am trying to place it into a dataframe using pandas, like this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
```

But it takes too long. Is there a better way to speed up the dataframe creation? I was considering changing the parameter `engine='c'`, since it says in the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
"engine{‘c’, ‘python’}, optional
Parser engine to use. The C engine is faster while the python engine is currently more feature-complete."
```

But I dont see much gain in speed

Comment: chunk it up and then do the data analysis in parts.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-in-chunks

Comment: reading `csv` files is a fairly slow process. If this is a file you expect to Import/Output frequently then you should pay the upfront cost of reading the csv once, and save it in a format that pandas can read much more quickly: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/io.html#performance-considerations. Based on their timings, `.pkl` files can be read nearly 50x faster than .csv files

Comment: Do you use the same CSV many times? If so, save it in something like parquet or arrow after you've managed to get it into memory once.

Comment: maybe take a look at `Dask`which is very similar to `Pandas`but supports multicore and handle large dataset. https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html. Kr.

Comment: @PaulBrennan thanks, I will look into it. Seems useful

Comment: Place it in a dB instead save on the I/O cost how many times are you reading said file ?

Comment: @ALollz Thanks for the approach, I am not sure if I can modify the input file, but  will try it

Comment: @tdelaney just read it once, then I keep operating with it to train a model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is you are not able to create the dataframe since the big size makes the operation to fail, you can check how to chunk it in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25962114/1773841)

In case it is created at some point, but you consider it is too slow, then you can use `datatable` to read the file, then convert to `pandas`, and continue with your operations:

```
import pandas as pd 
import datatable as dt

# Read with databale
datatable_df = dt.fread('myfile.csv')

# Then convert the dataframe into pandas
pandas_df = frame_datatable.to_pandas()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But later how slow is to convert from datatable to pandas? because if it takes too long, may not worth the entire process

Comment: @TonyBalboa actually not much longer than the reading operation. It will depend on the machine where you are running it, but the entire operation of reading + converting should be like a few seconds.

Comment: Thank you, actually it is much faster indeed