# Python divide dataframe into chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I have a 1 column df with 37365 rows. I would need to separate it in chunks like the below:

```
df[0:2499]
df[2500:4999]
df[5000:7499]
...
df[32500:34999]
df[35000:37364]
```

The idea would be to use this in a loop like the below (process_operation does not work for dfs larger than 2500 rows)

```
while chunk <len(df):
    process_operation(df[lower:upper])
```

EDIT:
I will be having different dataframes as inputs. Some of them will be smaller than 2500. What would be the best approach to also capture these?

```
Ej: df[0:1234] because 1234<2500
```

Comment: Most of the solutions to [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/312443/364696) and [What is the most “pythonic” way to iterate over a list in chunks?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/434287/364696) should apply here. Leaving this open as there might be a more clever way with dataframes.

Comment: And of course, having closed and unclosed the question, I can't close it now that I've found a proper duplicate [Pandas - Slice Large Dataframe in Chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44729727/364696).

Comment: Your edit doesn't change things; Python slicing happily accepts non-existent end points; when `df.shape[0]` is `1234`, `df[0:2500]` gets the exact same result as `df[0:1234]`.

Comment: Great. Then I will accept Serge Ballesta's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `range` function is enough here:

```
for start in range(0, len(df), 2500):
    process_operation(df[start:start+2500])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like that?

```
lower = 0
upper = 2499

while upper <= len(df):
    process_operation(df[lower:upper])
    lower += 2500
    upper += 2500
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use

```
import numpy as np
import math
    
chunk_max_size = 2500
chunks = int(math.ceil(len(df) / chunk_max_size)) 
for df_chunk in np.array_split(df, chunks):
    #where: len(df_chunk) <= 2500
```