# How to group by in pandas based on specific columns where each group has n number of rows? Also delete from the original dataframe IF POSSIBLE?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as follows-

```
a   b   c
x   2   3
y   2   3
z   3   2
w   1   5
(upto thousands of records)
```

I want to group this dataframe based on b,c such that each group has only n number of rows. If there are any more rows in the same group, I want to create a new group. That is the main problem statement.
I also want to delete these groups from the original dataframe if possible.

Sample output (with a little more explanation)  -

```
I basically want to loop on the df and am currently using the following code-

for x,y in df.groupby(['b','c']):
    print(y)
```

```
With this code Im getting the following groups:
a   b   c
x   2   3
y   2   3

a   b   c
z   3   2

a   b   c
w   1   5
```

```
Now lets say I want only 1(n) row in each group, this is the output Im looking for:
a   b   c
x   2   3

a   b   c
y   2   3

a   b   c
z   3   2

a   b   c
w   1   5
```

(And maybe delete these groups from the df too if possible)

Thank you!

Comment: can you give sample output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taken from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-into-chunks), I have modified the code for your question:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"a": ["x", "y", "z", "w"],
                   "b": [2, 2, 3, 1],
                   "c": [3, 3, 2, 5]})

n = 1

for x, y in df.groupby(['b','c']):
    list_df = [y[i: i+n] for i in range(0, y.shape[0], n)]
    for i in list_df:
        print(i)

#a  b  c
#w  1  5
#
#a  b  c
#x  2  3
#
#a  b  c
#y  2  3
#
#a  b  c
#z  3  2
```

This splits the grouped dataframe for length of `n` rows.  If you wanted to delete each group from the dataframe each time, you could add `df.drop(i.index)`, which will delete the index values (as these are carried through):

```
for x,y in df.groupby(['b','c']):
    list_df = [y[i: i+n] for i in range(0, y.shape[0], n)]
    for i in list_df:
        print(i)
        df = df.drop(i.index)
        print(df)
```

Comment: Thanks! This code does work, but is it suggested to drop rows from a df while looping on it?

Comment: No problem.  I would avoid dropping values in a loop if using `.iloc[]`, because results might be different to what you are expecting.  If you are using specific, fixed values, then it isn't a problem.