# Export dataset haveing more than 1048576 rows, in multiple sheets of single excel file, in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataset given as such:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

## Create an array
data = np.arange(7152123)
print(data)

## Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print("\n an df = \n", df)     

## Load the data in excel sheet    
df.to_excel('df.xlsx', index=False,header=False)
```

I get an error:

> f"This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: {num_rows}, {num_cols}
> " ValueError: This sheet is too large! Your sheet size is: 7152123, 1
> Max sheet size is: 1048576, 16384

The error comes because a single sheet of excel allows a maximum of 1048576 rows.

However, the dataset that I need to export has 7152123 rows

Can somebody please let me know how do I export such a huge dataset in multiple sheets of single excel file in Python?

Comment: Why are you doing this in the first place? It matters. Excel sheets can't have more than 1M rows. You can have multiple sheets in a workbook, each with 1M rows. Or you can load a lot more data than that into a PivotTable model using Excel itself.

Comment: Who's going to consume that data? It's probably better to use a different format. Even if they intend to use Excel, it may be better to use Power Pivot or Power Query to load the data from a better format.

Comment: The data is being generated in Python and then I need to import the data in MATLAB.

Comment: Can we export the data in 7 different sheets in the same excel file?

Comment: MATLAB can read multiple formats. In fact, Excel is a special case. Why not use CSV ie text files? Or Parquet files? HDF5? Using the correct format can have a huge impact

Comment: The MATLAB docs [mention Parquet as an option for Big Data files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-files-and-big-data.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav)

Comment: Thanks a lot @PanagiotisKanavos for your feedback. CSV format has helped me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The data is being generated in Python and then I need to import the data in MATLAB.

In that case I'd suggest *not* using Excel. Excel was built to analyze data, not exchange data.  It's not only that splitting up the data into 1M-row sheets is complex, the MATLAB code will have to read those sheets and recombine them in memory.

There are better formats for this. [to_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) can generate a single text file that can be read by MATLAB.

```
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Another option, for really large files that can't fit in memory, is Parquet. In the MATLAB docs  [Parquet Files](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/parquet-files.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) have their own section in the [Large Files and Big Data](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/large-files-and-big-data.html?s_tid=CRUX_lftnav) section.

The file can be generated with [to_parquet](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html) and read with MATLAB's [parquetread](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/parquetread.html) :

```
df.to_parquet('out.parquet')
```

```
T = parquetread('outages.parquet');
```

Finally, [rowfilter](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.io.rowfilter.html) can be used to filter data before importing it.

**BAD IDEA - Splitting into sheets**

This can be done by splitting the dataframe into several, then storing them into different sheets with the help of `ExcelWriter`. There are several relevant SO answers already. [This answer shows several options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44729807/134204), including using NumPy's `array_split` :

```
n=1048576
list_df = np.array_split(df, n)
```

The [to_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) docs show how to write to different sheets in the same file:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_name_2')
```

This can be done in a loop:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for i, d in enumerate(list_df):
        d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_name_{i}')
```

**Meaningful grouping**

If the data is meant for analysis using Excel, it makes sense to split the data using a meaningful grouping, assuming no group exceeds 1M rows:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx') as writer:  
    for name,d in df.groupby('AcctName'):
        d.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'Sheet_name_{name}')
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to set the [pandas.ExcelWriter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.ExcelWriter.html) object to `append mode`.

Here is an example where I slice the database in batches of 1000 rows and save each slice into a sheet.
Make sure you have an empty `output.xlsx` file in the same path, then try the following.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(10000)
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

with pd.ExcelWriter(path="output.xlsx", mode="a") as writer:
    for n in range(1, len(df), 1000):
        df.iloc[n:n+1000].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f'MySheet_{n}')
```

However, as already suggested, you should probably just save the data in a single csv file instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try splitting the dataframe in groups of max_rows:

```
# Split dataframe in groups of 1048576 rows
max_rows = 1048576
# Round up the number
rows = len(df)
if rows > max_rows:
    n_of_groups = math.ceil(rows / max_rows)
    for i in range(n_of_groups):
        start = i*max_rows
        end = (i+1)*max_rows
        if end < rows:
            df_write = df[start:end]
        else:
            df_write = df[start:]
        print(f'Write df_write with {len(df_write)} rows on Excel file')
```

Output:

```
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 1048576 rows on Excel file
Write df_write with 860667 rows on Excel file
```

Hope it works!

Comment: This isn't a good solution even if it answered the exact question - how do you store those dataframes into sheets in the same file?. Splitting lots of data into multiple sheets is a bad idea to begin with