# correct use of the neo4j python driver for large queries

Tags: python, neo4j

I am using the `neo4j` driver in Python and in my jupyter notebook I have this code:

```
driver = GraphDatabase.driver('bolt://localhost:7687',\
              auth=(os.getenv('NEO_USERNAME'),     
                    os.getenv('NEO_PASSWORD')))
def create_constraint(tx):
    tx.run("CREATE CONSTRAINT entityIndex IF NOT EXISTS FOR (e:Entity) REQUIRE (e.EntityId) IS UNIQUE")

def create_entity(tx, row):
    tx.run("MERGE (e:Entity {EntityId: $entity_id}) ON CREATE SET n.LastAccess = timestamp() ON MATCH SET n.LastAccess = timestamp()", entity_id=row["entity_id"])
    
with driver.session() as session:
    session.execute_write(create_constraint)

with driver.session() as session:
    for idx, row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total=len(df)):
        try:
            session.execute_write(create_entity, row)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
```

I have to say that it works fine for small data frames, but as soon as there are more than 200000 rows, performances start to degrade considerably...

I am wondering if I am using it correctly and of course if there are more performant ways to accomplish the same task.

EDIT AFTER ANSWER
if you want to stick to the dataframe, you can do:

```
list_df = np.array_split(df, 10000)

for adf in tqdm(list_df, total=len(list_df)):
    try:
        records, _, _ = driver.execute_query(query, data=adf.to_dict(orient="records"), database_="neo4j")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to use `UNWIND` and batch your rows. Here is a Python snippet I'm using in my trainings with Python :

```py
import csv
from neo4j import GraphDatabase

URI = 'bolt://localhost:7687'
AUTH = ('neo4j', 'password')
driver = GraphDatabase.driver(URI, auth=AUTH)

query = '''
    UNWIND $trackInfos AS trackInfo
    CREATE (track:Track {id: trackInfo.id}) 
    SET track.name = trackInfo.name
    '''

BATCH_SIZE = 10_000
current_batch = []

def commit_batch(current_batch):
    records, _, _ = driver.execute_query(
        query,
        trackInfos=current_batch,
        database_='testload'
    )
    # reset current_batch to empty list
    current_batch.clear()

def process_row(row, current_batch):
    current_batch.append(row)
    if len(current_batch) >= BATCH_SIZE:
        commit_batch(current_batch)

with open('./files/sample_tracks_medium.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(file)
    for row in reader:
        process_row(row, current_batch)
    else:
        commit_batch(current_batch)
```

The same strategy is applied for relationships, you generally would have the following structure with UNWIND :

```
UNWIND $rels AS rel
MATCH (start:Label) WHERE start.id = rel.startId
MATCH (end:Label) WHERE end.id = rel.endId
// CREATE or MERGE depending on the need
CREATE (start)-[:REL_TYPE]->(end)
```

And a couple of resources :

- UNWIND https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/unwind/
- Cypher fast import ( old but still relevant ) https://neo4j.com/blog/cypher-write-fast-furious/
- Python driver performance recommendations https://neo4j.com/docs/python-manual/current/performance/

Comment: so i guess the point is to do batch writings, but maybe I can get there also from a dataframe

Comment: Yes, probably you can slice your dataframe into chunks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44729727/pandas-slice-large-dataframe-into-chunks

Comment: do you have any suggestions on link creation? can that part work in the same way?

Comment: @SimoneGabbriellini I amended the answer with an example Cypher for relationships