# Python - How to split a dataframe into a third and two thirds horizontally

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe (`df`) with about 300 rows. The column names are `'Description'`, `'Impact'` and `'lower_desc'`:

```
    Description                                       Impact    lower_desc
0   BICC's mission in its current phase extends th...   BAD [bicc's, mission, current, phase, extends, pre...
1   Narrative Impact Report\r\n\r\nDuring the cour...   GOOD    [narrative, impact, report, course, project, (...
2   Our findings have been used by social psycholo...   BAD [findings, used, social, psychologists, intere...
3   The data set has been used for secondary analy...   BAD [data, set, used, secondary, analysis, byt, es...
4   So far it seems that our research outcome has ...   BAD [far, seems, outcome, 'used', people, (educati...
5   Our findings on the effects of urbanisation on...   BAD [findings, effects, urbanisation, cognition, r...
6   The research findings have been used by a rang...   GOOD    [findings, used, range, societal, bodies,, inc...
7   In the last year we have disseminated the rese...   BAD [last, year, disseminated, five, different, wo...
8   \r\nThis research has been concerned with how ...   BAD [concerned, people, withhold, actions,, brain,...
9   The Centre has run a varied programme of cours...   BAD [centre, run, varied, programme, courses,, mas...
10  We presented evidence at one of the seminars o...   BAD [presented, evidence, one, seminars, additiona.
...
```

I am producing a training and test set, so I want to split the dataframe into two i.e. the first 200 rows go into `df1` and the remaining 100 go into `df2`. There may be more than 300 rows or less.

How would one go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will allocate the first 200 rows into `df1` then anything after row 200 into `df2`:

```
df1 = df.iloc[:200]
df2 = df.iloc[200:]
```

If you want to stop at row 300 do this instead:

```
df2 = df.iloc[200:300]
```

You might want to reset the index on df2 to avoid it starting from 200. You can do:

```
df2 = df.iloc[200:300].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: Thank you Dillon! Really appreciate the quick response :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd                                                                           
                                                                                              
src = "/path/to/your/data/data.csv"                                                    
df = pd.read_csv(src, sep="\t")                                                               

# Cast to int to avoid decimals
half_len = int(len(df) / 2)                                                                        
                                                                                              
# Retrieve the first half of dataframe                                                        
df_one = df.iloc[:half_len]                                                                   
                                                                                              
#       Description                                       Impact    lower_desc                
# 0   BICC's mission in its current phase extend...                                           
# 1   Narrative Impact Report\r\n\r\nDuring the ...                                           
# 2   Our findings have been used by social psyc...                                           
# 3   The data set has been used for secondary a...                                           
# 4   So far it seems that our research outcome ...                                           
# Retrieve the other part of dataframe                                                        
df_two = df.iloc[half_len:]                                                                   
                                                                                              
#        Description                                       Impact    lower_desc               
# 5   Our findings on the effects of urbanisatio...                                           
# 6   The research findings have been used by a ...                                           
# 7   In the last year we have disseminated the ...                                           
# 8   \r\nThis research has been concerned with ...                                           
# 9   The Centre has run a varied programme of c...                                           
# 10  We presented evidence at one of the semina...
```

Comment: Ahh, thank you. This is perfect, as I was wondering how to do halfs (or thirds etc)

Comment: @ScoutEU If you want to split it into n equal parts you can use `np.array_split(df, n)`. See [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: @Alvaro-nortes You should note that this will only work where `half_len` or any other `third_len` etc. is an integer result (whole number) and will fail otherwise. Even `df.iloc[:150.0]` will fail since `150.0` is a float and pandas expects an int

Comment: Thank you Dillon!

Comment: Thank's @dillion I have modified the answer