# How to randomly split a DataFrame into several smaller DataFrames?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter

I'm having trouble randomly splitting DataFrame `df` into groups of smaller `DataFrames`.

```
df
  movie_id  1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  borda
0   1       5   4   0   4   4   0   0   0   4   0   0   21
1   2       3   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   6   
2   3       4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
3   4       3   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   4   0   5   17  
4   5       3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   
5   6       5   0   0   0   0   0   0   5   0   0   0   10  
6   7       4   0   0   0   2   5   3   4   4   0   0   22  
7   8       1   0   0   0   4   5   0   0   0   4   0   14  
8   9       5   0   0   0   4   5   0   0   4   5   0   23  
9   10      3   2   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   9   
10  11      2   0   4   0   0   3   3   0   4   2   0   18  
11  12      5   0   0   0   4   5   0   0   5   2   0   21  
12  13      5   4   0   0   2   0   0   0   3   0   0   14  
13  14      5   4   0   0   5   0   0   0   0   0   0   14  
14  15      5   0   0   0   3   0   0   0   0   5   5   18  
15  16      5   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   9   
16  17      3   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   
17  18      4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
18  19      5   3   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   12  
19  20      4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
20  21      1   0   0   3   3   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   
21  22      4   0   0   0   3   5   5   0   5   4   0   26  
22  23      4   0   0   0   4   3   0   0   5   0   0   16  
23  24      3   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   3   0   10
```

I've tried `sample` and `arange`, but with bad results.

```
ran1 = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=False, random_state=1)
ran2 = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=False, random_state=1)
ran3 = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=False, random_state=1)
ran4 = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=False, random_state=1)
ran5 = df.sample(frac=0.2, replace=False, random_state=1)

print(ran1, '\n')
print(ran2, '\n')
print(ran3, '\n')
print(ran4, '\n')
print(ran5, '\n')
```

This turned out to be 5 exact same `DataFrames`.

```
   movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda  
13    14     5  4  0  0  5  0  0  0   0   0   0     14  
18    19     5  3  0  0  4  0  0  0   0   0   0     12  
3     4      3  0  0  0  0  5  0  0   4   0   5     17  
14    15     5  0  0  0  3  0  0  0   0   5   5     18  
20    21     1  0  0  3  3  0  0  0   0   0   0      7
```

Also I've tried :

```
g = df.groupby(['movie_id'])
h = np.arange(g.ngroups)
np.random.shuffle(h)

df[g.ngroup().isin(h[:6])]
```

The output :

```
    movie_id    1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  borda   
4      5        3   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   3   
6      7        4   0   0   0   2   5   3   4   4   0   0   22  
7      8        1   0   0   0   4   5   0   0   0   4   0   14  
16     17       3   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   7   
17     18       4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   4   
18     19       5   3   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   12
```

But there's still only one smaller group, other datas from `df` aren't grouped.

I'm expecting the smaller groups to be split evenly by using percentage. And the whole `df` should be split into groups.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe) help?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use `np.array_split`

```
shuffled = df.sample(frac=1)
result = np.array_split(shuffled, 5)
```

`df.sample(frac=1)` shuffle the rows of `df`. Then use `np.array_split` split it into parts that have equal size.

It gives you:

```
for part in result:
    print(part,'\n')
```

```
    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
5          6  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  5   0   0   0     10
4          5  3  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      3
7          8  1  0  0  0  4  5  0  0   0   4   0     14
16        17  3  0  0  4  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      7
22        23  4  0  0  0  4  3  0  0   5   0   0     16 

    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
13        14  5  4  0  0  5  0  0  0   0   0   0     14
14        15  5  0  0  0  3  0  0  0   0   5   5     18
21        22  4  0  0  0  3  5  5  0   5   4   0     26
1          2  3  0  0  3  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      6
20        21  1  0  0  3  3  0  0  0   0   0   0      7 

    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
10        11  2  0  4  0  0  3  3  0   4   2   0     18
9         10  3  2  0  0  0  4  0  0   0   0   0      9
11        12  5  0  0  0  4  5  0  0   5   2   0     21
8          9  5  0  0  0  4  5  0  0   4   5   0     23
12        13  5  4  0  0  2  0  0  0   3   0   0     14 

    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
18        19  5  3  0  0  4  0  0  0   0   0   0     12
3          4  3  0  0  0  0  5  0  0   4   0   5     17
0          1  5  4  0  4  4  0  0  0   4   0   0     21
23        24  3  0  0  4  0  0  0  0   0   3   0     10
6          7  4  0  0  0  2  5  3  4   4   0   0     22 

    movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
17        18  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      4
2          3  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      4
15        16  5  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   4   0   0      9
19        20  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      4
```

Comment: i like this one. :) +1

Comment: This is so nice and clean. Thanks a lot!

Comment: but what if we want different sizes?

Answer (score 2):

A simple demo:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"movie_id": np.arange(1, 25),
          "borda": np.random.randint(1, 25, size=(24,))})
n_split = 5
# the indices used to select parts from dataframe
ixs = np.arange(df.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(ixs)
# np.split cannot work when there is no equal division
# so we need to find out the split points ourself
# we need (n_split-1) split points
split_points = [i*df.shape[0]//n_split for i in range(1, n_split)]
# use these indices to select the part we want
for ix in np.split(ixs, split_points):
    print(df.iloc[ix])
```

The result:

```
    borda  movie_id
8       3         9
10      2        11
22     14        23
7      14         8

    borda  movie_id
0      16         1
20      4        21
17     15        18
15      1        16
6       6         7

    borda  movie_id
9       9        10
19      4        20
5       1         6
16     23        17
21     20        22

    borda  movie_id
11     24        12
23      5        24
1      22         2
12      7        13
18     15        19

    borda  movie_id
3      11         4
14     10        15
2       6         3
4       7         5
13     21        14
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you can do this:

```
frames={}
for e,i in enumerate(np.split(df,6)):
    frames.update([('df_'+str(e+1),pd.DataFrame(np.random.permutation(i),columns=df.columns))])
print(frames['df_1'])

   movie_id  1  2  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11  12  borda
0         4  3  0  0  0  0  5  0  0   4   0   5     17
1         3  4  0  0  0  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      4
2         2  3  0  0  3  0  0  0  0   0   0   0      6
3         1  5  4  0  4  4  0  0  0   4   0   0     21
```

**Explanation**: `np.split(df,6)` splits the df to 6 equal size. 
`pd.DataFrame(np.random.permutation(i),columns=df.columns)` randomly reshapes the rows so creating a dataframe with this information and storing in a dictionary names `frames`.

Finally print the dictionary by calling each keys, values as dataframe will be returned. you can try print `frames['df_1']` , `frames['df_2']` , etc. It will return random permutations of a split of the dataframe.