# How to split a data frame into n parts of equal size? (number of observations)

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the format:

```
ID      Price
1          20
2          15
3          30
4          40
5          15
```

with a ID.count equal to 1000

and let's say I want to create 5 data frames with each 200 rows of the original data frame, in the original sequence as well. How can I split it like this?

Comment: When you say “in the original sequence as well”, you mean that you want to conserve the ordering, right?

Comment: yes! @AlexanderCécile

Comment: There are some good answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17315737/11301900)!

Comment: There might be a better solution if you can share a bit more about the context and your goals.

Comment: What have you tried so far based on your own research, and what was wrong with your attempts?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)