# Divide a large dataframe into smaller sub dataframes in order

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

Is there any way to divide the very large data frame into smaller 5 sub-data frames with equal parts? I cannot use the train test split because it does not keep the data in order.
The solution that already exists [Split a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe). It does not serve my purpose. I have tried it, and it gives this below mentioned output which is not desired output.Input is

```
new_dict1 = {'ABW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'BCW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},
    'CBW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':0},'MCW':{'ABR':1,'BPR':1,'CBR':0,'DBR':1},
    'DBW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'MNW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},
    'RBW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'EBW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},
    'GBW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0},'HBW':{'ABR':0,'BPR':0,'CBR':1,'DBR':0}}
import pandas as pd
df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_dict1,orient="index")
```

The output that I have got is

```
  [  ABR  BPR  CBR  DBR
     ABW    1    1    1    0
     BCW    0    0    1    0
     CBW    1    1    0    0
     MCW    1    1    0    1
     DBW    0    0    1    0,      ABR  BPR  CBR  DBR
     MNW    0    0    1    0
     RBW    0    0    1    0
     EBW    0    0    1    0
     GBW    0    0    1    0
     HBW    0    0    1    0]
```

This is not desired output. Desired output is divide the large dataframe into five sub-data farmes.

Comment: the logic for splitting is unclear

Comment: @mozway, I want to divide the data frame into five sub-data frames.

Comment: By dividing the large data frame into 5 subdata frames. In this case, in every data frame two rows should be present. In first sub data frame, first two rows, second next two rows and so on. I want to apply it to a very large data frame.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe

Comment: @GedasMiksenas, I have seen this one, this is not serving my purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my comment. Here is an example, note it's probably not the best approach..:

```
import numpy as np
dfs = np.array_split(df2, 5)
for index, df in enumerate(dfs):
    globals()['df%s' % index] = pd.DataFrame(df)

df3
```