# Fill Word Merge Fields from dataset using Python

Tags: python, mailmerge

I am trying to fill a Word template that contains 10 Merge Fields on one single page ("guest_1", ..., "guest_10") with a column from a dataset. The template can be found here: https://file.io/GVO4hyOwBCiv

I was able to fill the Word template with constant data using the `docx-mailmerge` package (see below in the code `# This Works` session), but unsuccessful by trying to replicate the result by looping a dataset (see below `# This does not work`).

I first need to create objects of type `dict` (in my code below, I call them `guests_page_1` and `guests_page_2`). Each of these `dict` objects should have up to 10 items (e.g. `{'guest_1': 'Name 1', 'guest_2': 'Name 1'}`). So the dataset (in my example below, `guests`) should be split into multiple objects (each one coining up to 10 items) and then, using the `merge_templates` function,  replicate the template filling onto multiple pages (depending on the size of the dataset).

In summary for the example below: I need to split the `guests` (which contains 18 names) dataset into 2 objects of type `dict` (`guests_page_1` and `guests_page_2`). `guests_page_1` should contain the first 10 names and `guests_page_2` the remaining 8 names. Then, I need to add `guests_page_1` and `guests_page_2` into the `merge_templates` function.

```
# Requirements: python -m pip install docx-mailmerge

# Import packages
from natsort import natsorted
import os

from mailmerge import MailMerge
import pandas as pd


# Set working directory to user's 'Downloads' folder
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads'))

# Import template
document = MailMerge('Template.docx')

# Get set of Merge Fields
document_guest_fields = document.get_merge_fields()

# Sort Merge Fields
document_guest_fields = natsorted(document_guest_fields)



## This works

guests_page_1 = {}
guests_page_2 = {}

for i in document_guest_fields:
    guests_page_1[i] = 'Name 1'

for i in document_guest_fields:
    guests_page_2[i] = 'Name 2'

document.merge_templates([guests_page_1, guests_page_2], separator='continuous_section')
document.write('Template-Output.docx')

document.close()



## This does not work

# Create dummy dataset with 18 names
guests = [
    ['Tom'],
    ['Jones'],
    ['Krystal'],
    ['Albert'],
    ['Paloma'],
    ['Shania'],
    ['Max'],
    ['Steve'],
    ['Paul'],
    ['Patrick'],
    ['Lucia'],
    ['Rachel'],
    ['Ray'],
    ['Jessica'],
    ['Julianna'],
    ['Lucille'],
    ['Leandro'],
    ['Vincent'],
    ]

guests = pd.DataFrame(guests, columns = ['name'])


guests_page_1 = {}

for index, row in guests.iterrows():
    for i in document_guest_fields:
        guests_page_1[i] = row['name']

document.merge_templates([guests_page_1], separator='continuous_section')
document.write('Template-Output.docx')

document.close()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this issue? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
# Import packages
from natsort import natsorted
import os

from mailmerge import MailMerge
import pandas as pd

# Split dataframe into chunks of up to 10 rows - adapted from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28882020/9195104
def split_dataframe(df, chunk_size=10000):

    chunks = list()
    num_chunks = len(df) // chunk_size+1

    for i in range(num_chunks):
        chunks.append(df[i*chunk_size:(i+1)*chunk_size])

    for i in range(len(chunks)):
        chunks[i].index = pd.RangeIndex(start=1, stop=len(chunks[i])+1, step=1)
        chunks[i].reset_index(inplace=True, level=0)
        chunks[i] = chunks[i].rename(columns={'index': 'merge_field'})
        chunks[i]['merge_field'] = chunks[i]['merge_field'].astype(str)
        chunks[i]['merge_field'] = chunks[i]['merge_field'].str.replace(r'^(.*)$', r'guest_\1', regex=True)

    return chunks



# Set working directory to user's 'Downloads' folder
os.chdir(os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Downloads'))

# Import template
document = MailMerge('Template.docx')

# Get set of Merge Fields
document_guest_fields = document.get_merge_fields()

# Sort Merge Fields
document_guest_fields = natsorted(document_guest_fields)

# Create dummy dataset with 18 names
guests = [
    ['Tom'],
    ['Jones'],
    ['Krystal'],
    ['Albert'],
    ['Paloma'],
    ['Shania'],
    ['Max'],
    ['Steve'],
    ['Paul'],
    ['Patrick'],
    ['Lucia'],
    ['Rachel'],
    ['Ray'],
    ['Jessica'],
    ['Julianna'],
    ['Lucille'],
    ['Leandro'],
    ['Vincent'],
    ]

guests = pd.DataFrame(guests, columns = ['name'])

# Split guests dataframe
guests = split_dataframe(guests, chunk_size=10)

# Create guests dictionary object
guests_list = {}

for i in range(len(guests)):
    guests_list[i] = dict(zip(guests[i]['merge_field'], guests[i]['name']))

# Fill Word Template file
document.merge_templates(list(guests_list.values()), separator='continuous_section')
document.write('Template-Output.docx')
document.close()
```