# Read Excel file with data more than 1m and split into multiple files using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv

I'm trying to read Excel/csv file with data more than 1m and split it

**For example:**

I have Excel file with 2.7M data and now I want to split it in 3 files of 0.9M data using python.

**Code:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/excels/file.xlsx")

n_partitions = 3

for i in range(n_partitions):
    sub_df = df.iloc[(i*n_paritions):((i+1)*n_paritions)]
    sub_df.to_excel(f"/output/path/to/test-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
```

I tried this it's working fine for less data but want something that can help when we have data more than 1m as we all know Excel have limitation upto 1m to show data.

Comment: your partition logic is wrong, you need to divide the total row with n_partitions and then increment by this value in each iteration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split a large pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> as we all know Excel have limitation upto 1m to show data.

Keeping this condition in mind and in a scenario where you want to scale up at any time given dynamic changes, instead of doing mental math every time for the number of partitions, keep the row/records limit defined as per your need. That way you control how much data you keep in each partition rather than the other way around.

```
limit = 100000
```

Here I've kept it at 100,000 for slightly better readability in Excel.
Then you can simply go ahead and partition using the dataframe.iloc functionality as you have done originally.

```
n = 1
i = 0
while (i < df.shape[0]):
    sub_df = df.iloc[i:limit+i]
    sub_df.to_excel(f"/output/path/to/test-{n}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
    n += 1
    i += limit
```

It's a rather naive approach but it works and reads well.

Answer (score 1):

#### Correction

***Misunderstood the question at the beginning, so my option only reflects the split by number of lines - There is a well asked and answered question that will cover this issue [split large dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17315737/split-a-large-pandas-dataframe)***

---

Split dataframe by given number of rows - You could adjust your [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#ranges) and extend it by the `step` parameter that will get the value of your `n_partitions`:

```
for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n_partitions):
    df[i:i+n_partitions].to_excel(f"/output/path/to/test-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
```

Exanple:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("/path/to/excels/file.xlsx")

n_partitions = 3
for i in range(0,df.shape[0],n_partitions):
    df[i:i+n_partitions].to_excel(f"/output/path/to/test-{i}.xlsx", sheet_name="a")
```